# I cannot make a directory using mkdir in windows

Tags: windows, cmd, directory, mkdir

I cannot make directory by using mkdir
code : in administrative cmd :

```
C:\Windows\System32>cd C:\Users\jrc12\OneDrive\Documents\pythonProjects\DjangoMosh

C:\Users\jrc12\OneDrive\Documents\pythonProjects\DjangoMosh>mkdir storefront
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Please tell me the problem.

I am expecting to create a directory named storefront in the given path.

Comment: The formatting in your question was a bit weird. Can you confirm that what you actually type is just `mkdir storefront` ?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming problem, and it certainly isn't a Python problem.  I suspect that it is something to do with using OneDrive.   Can you (for example) list the DjangoMosh directory?

Answer (score 1):

have you already tried possible [solution](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-command-line-problem-mkdir-the-system/715176f3-19c9-42f3-ada1-5c9029355706) from Microsoft adviser? Also, have you tried another command for that?

```
md folder
```